# How to keep the row after filtering out?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, filtering

my step is like this, I will filter the dataframe first, then groupby to get the dataset I want. For example, my df is like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([["Mon", 3, "A"], ["Tue", 6, "A"], ["Tue", 4, "A"], ["Wed", pd.np.nan, "A"], ["Thu", 9, "A"], ["Fri", 1, "A"], ["Sat", 2, "A"], ["Sun", 3, "B"]], columns=["date", "value", "class"])
```

The dataframe "test" looks like this:

```
        date  value  Class
0        Mon    3     A
1        Tue    6     A
2        Tue    4     A
3        Wed    0     A
4        Thu    9     A
5        Fri    1     A
6        Sat    2     A
7        Sun    3     B
```

I will first filter all A by `test = test[test["class"] == "A"]`
Then I will aggregate by `new_df = test(["date"],dropna=False)["value"].sum()`

Because as you can see, Sunday will be filtered out in the first step. The result dataframe after the aggregation above will have no Sunday in it. But the final data set  needs to keep Sunday there.

My goal is like this after grouping by "date".

```
        date  value 
0        Mon    3    
1        Tue    10    
2        Wed    0    
3        Thu    9     
4        Fri    1     
5        Sat    2     
6        Sun    0
```

This is only a simplified version. My actual situation is, the "data" column is really a date column in reality, like 1-Jan-2021. The data set is a few years long. But the filtering will filter some dates out in the first step (like the example above, Sunday is gone after filtering). However, I want all the dates in those years to be in my result dataframe. How can i achieve it?

Comment: You say `test(["date"],dropna=False)` but, don't you mean sum function after `test`? e.g. `test.XXX(["date"],dropna=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about set values that you don't want to keep to be 0 first

```
test.loc[test['class']!='A', 'value'] = 0
test.groupby('date')['value'].sum()
```

```
date
Fri     1.0
Mon     3.0
Sat     2.0
Sun     0.0
Thu     9.0
Tue    10.0
Wed     0.0
```

Comment: but a new problem comes up, after setting those I don't want to zeros, when I do groupby with mean() function, the number is not right. The sum() ones are correct. Is it by default, the mean() function includes all the zeros?

Comment: yes the mean would definitely include all 0. To make mean work you can set them to `np.nan`

Comment: Thank you Li! Yes I got it

Comment: right. Care that this would give `np.nan` in results after aggregation so you would need to fill them with 0 later `.fillna(0)`

Comment: works like charms!